# Understanding Two's complement to float(Texas Instruments Sensor Tag)

Tags: python, floating-point, sensors, twos-complement, texas-instruments

I found some sample code to extract temperature from the Texas Instruments Sensor Tag on github:
https://github.com/msaunby/ble-sensor-pi/blob/master/sensortag/sensor_calcs.py

I don't understand what the following code does:

```
tosigned = lambda n: float(n-0x10000) if n>0x7fff else float(n)
```

How i read the above piece of code:

```
if n>0x7fff: n = float(n-0x10000)
else n = float(n)
```

Basically what is happening is that the two's complement value(n) is converted to float. Why should this only happen when the value of n is greater than 0x7fff? If the value is 0x7fff or smaller, then we just convert i to float. Why? I don't understand this.

The sample code from Texas Instruments can be found here:
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/SensorTag_User_Guide#SensorTag_Android_Development

Why is the return value devided by 128.0 in this function in the TI sample code?

```
private double extractAmbientTemperature(BluetoothGattCharacteristic c) {
    int offset = 2;
    return shortUnsignedAtOffset(c, offset) / 128.0;
}
```

I did ask this to the developer, but didn't get a reply.

Comment: Have you looked at the difference between e.g. `float(0x8fff)` and `float(0x8fff-0x10000)`? The clue is in the name `tosigned`!

Comment: Yes i understand that, but why would it only be  converted to signed only if the value is larger than 0x7fff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On disk and in memory integers are stored to a certain bit-width.  Modern Python's `int`s allows us to ignore most of that detail because they can magically expand to whatever size is necessary, but sometimes when we get values from disk or other systems we have to think about how they are actually stored.

The positive values of a 16-bit signed integer will be stored in the range `0x0001`-`0x7fff`, and its negative values from `0x8000`-`0xffff`.  If this value was read in some way that didn't already check the sign bit (perhaps as an unsigned integer, or part of a longer integer, or assembled from two bytes) then we need to recover the sign.

How?  Well, if the value is over `0x7fff` we know that it *should* be negative, and negative values are stored as [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Two.27s_complement).  So we simply subtract `0x10000` from it and we get the negative value.

Comment: Isn't it 0x0001-0x7fff for postive integers?

Comment: @MeesterPatat Looks like I had a brain fart and wrote 7999 instead of 7fff originally.  Steve fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

So you're converting between signed hex and floats. In python, signed floats are displayed as having a negative sign, so you can ignore the way it's actually represented in memory. But in hex, the negative part of the number is represented as part of the value. So, to convert correctly, the shift is put in.

You can play with this yourself using the Python interpreter:

```
tosigned = lambda n: float(n-0x10000) if n>0x7fff else float(n)
print(tosigned(0x3fff))
```

versus:

```
unsigned = lambda n: float(n)
```

Check this out to learn more:

http://www.swarthmore.edu/NatSci/echeeve1/Ref/BinaryMath/NumSys.html

Comment: I understand what you're saying, so a hex value of 0x7fff and smaller can never be negative if it has two bytes because the msb can't be 1(7 in binary is 0111). Because 0x7fff and smaller arent negative numbers, we don't have to convert it? Am i understanding it correctly?